# C++ constructor error

Tags: c++

For example I have this constructor:

```
member(char* name,char* lastName,int age, char* gender );
```

and I have this on my main function to create the member.

```
member("John","Smith",20);
```

Since I only provided 3 out of 4 parameters I get the error:
candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided.
 How to I fix it so that even if I missed a parameter, it just skips it.

Comment: Use parameters with default values.

Comment: How do I do it?  Does it work if in my main function I create 2 members: e.g member("Mary","Smith","Female");
member("John","Smith",20);

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen when you call it with those three arguments?

Comment: off topic: `member("John","Smith",20);` should be tagged by your compiler with at least a warning. "John" is a `const char *` and treating it as a `char *` allows writing to a potentially unwritable location.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify a default value for the last argument. Something like:

```
member(char *name, char *lastName, int age, char* gender = NULL);
```

Then when the last argument is not specified it'll take the default value of NULL.

Comment: A bit of nitpicking here: Encourage the use of `nullptr` sir

Comment: @grigor I tried this but it ask me to do the default value for each parameter. and when I do that I fet ambigous error for calling the constructor.

Comment: @juji I'm not sure I understand. Who asks you to give a default value for each parameter? And for your second question, if you do default values as well as a constructor overload then there will be potential ambiguity. So if you have a constructor with all of its parameters with a default value, as well as a constructor with no parameters, then there will be ambiguity when you call a constructor with no parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can create overrrides of the functions for situations where more or less parameters are needed.

For example, for your situation, you can make two constructors, with the same name (obviously), except one takes the 4 parameters and handles it appropriately, and the other takes 3 and handles it its own way.

Example:

```
member(char name, char lastName, int age){
    //Do stuff here for the situation where 3 parameters are inputed
}

member(char name, char lastName, int age, char gender){
    //Do stuff here for the situation where 4 parameters are inputed
}
```

Comment: I need to use only one constructor for for this one @Bhaskar

Answer (score 1):

You can provide multiple signatures for one function, for example:

```
member(char* name, char* lastName, int age)
```

and

```
member(char* name, char* lastName, int age, char* gender)
```